# Cannot Lock Desktop

Tags: login, lightdm, lock-screen

I had been messing around trying to customize the guest user accoun and came across "Custom startup commands for LightDM guest session", so naturally I clicked it and nothing happened.

[image]

Login
However, now I cannot lock my computer when I close the lid or by pressing the dedicated button. I'd like to just make it as it was before I clicked it.

Edit (1)
Output of:
 cat /usr/share/lightdm/guest-session/skel/.config/autostart/guest-          session-startup.desktop

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Name=Custom startup commands for LightDM guest session
    Type=Application
    NoDisplay=true
    Exec=/usr/lib/lightdm/guest-session-auto.sh
    X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=lightdm
```

Edit (2)
output of /usr/lib/lightdm/guest-session-auto.sh
https://pastebin.com/yvQfnYjk

Edit (3)
output of gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.lockdown

```
org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-command-line false
org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-application-handlers false
org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-user-switching false
org.gnome.desktop.lockdown user-administration-disabled false
org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-printing false
org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-log-out false
org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-print-setup false
org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-save-to-disk false
```

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the computer since you clicked that?  There might be a chance that something might be running twice now causing issues.

Comment: Yes I have, I even just did it right now to be sure. I still have the same effect, I press lock, the screen turns off, flashes just a little and then turns right back on.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1025599/edit) your question and put in the contents of `cat /usr/share/lightdm/guest-session/skel/.config/autostart/Custom\ startup\ commands*`

Comment: I included the output in the latest edit

Comment: If I look at `/usr/lib/lightdm/guest-session-auto.sh` on my 16.04 VM, the first thing it does is "disable screen locking" with a bunch of gsettings calls - assuming you're using Unity or Gnome, can you add the output of `gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.lockdown` please?

Comment: I've included it in the pastebin above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

output of gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.lockdown
shows

> org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen **true**

In order to change it back to false, I had installed dconf-editor using,

```
sudo apt-get install dcof-editor
```

Once installed, open the GUI application and follow the path org>gnome>desktop>lockdown>Disable Screen Lockout

Simply remove the checkmark and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

### Command-line method

If you want to quickly change the lock screen setting, without downloading and installing `dconf-editor`, use this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

To display the current setting use:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
```